# ER_TOO_BIG_SELECT

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Выдает такую ошибку:

> Invalid query: The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay

Прописывал в консоли команду `SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;` но она не помогла.

Супер прав хостинг не дает, поэтому команда 
`SET GLOBAL max_join_size=18446744073709551615;` тоже не работает

Самое странное, что на одном хостинге не выдает такую ошибку, а на другом она есть.

Comment: Хостинг защищается от того, чтобы на нём выполняли слишком жирные запросы. Это, скорее всего, прихоть хостинга и предполагается, что пользователи со своей стороны это не обойдут. Общайтесь с поддержкой хостинга.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую